# Список на основе статической структуры C++

Tags: c++, структуры, список, структуры-данных

Реализовывал список на основе статической структуры, и куда-то пропадает  строка 5 и 17 при выводе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <conio.h>   
#include <string>    
#include <windows.h> 
using namespace std;

struct TypeList
{
    string name;
    int spot;
};

static TypeList List[20];  // размер списка
static TypeList New_el;

void Add_to_beginning(TypeList New_el) //функция добавления элемента в начало списка
{
    int i = 20;
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        List[i + 1] = List[i];
        i--;
    };
    List[0].name = New_el.name;
    List[0].spot = New_el.spot;
}

void Add_to_end(TypeList New_el, int size) //функция добавления элемента в конец списка
{
    List[size + 1].name = New_el.name;
    List[size + 1].spot = New_el.spot;

}

void Insert(TypeList New_el, int position) //функция добавления элемента в произвольное место списка
{
    int j = 20;

    while (j >= position)
    {
        List[j + 1] = List[j];
        j--;
    };

    List[position].name = New_el.name;
    List[position].spot = New_el.spot;
}

void Deletion_from_beginning() //функция удаления элемента из начала списка
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 20)
    {
        List[i] = List[i + 1];
        i++;
    };

}


void Delete(int pos_del) //функция удаления элемента из произвольного места списка
{
    int i = pos_del;
    while (i <= 20)
    {
        List[i] = List[i + 1];
        i++;
    };

}

void main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

    List[0].name = "Балашенко Игорь";
    List[0].spot = 1;

    List[1].name = "Бибик Сергей";
    List[1].spot = 2;

    List[2].name = "Волохов Владислав";
    List[2].spot = 3;

    List[3].name = "Гостев Дмитрий";
    List[3].spot = 4;

    List[4].name = "Гришин Роман";
    List[4].spot = 5;

    List[5].name = "Караман Григорий";
    List[5].spot = 6;

    List[6].name = "Кирюткин Юрий";
    List[6].spot = 7;

    List[7].name = "Кузнецов Дмитрий";
    List[7].spot = 8;

    List[8].name = "Малютин Александр";
    List[8].spot = 9;

    List[9].name = "Нестеренко Евгений";
    List[9].spot = 10;

    List[10].name = "Орлов Илья";
    List[10].spot = 11;

    List[11].name = "Родин Владислав";
    List[11].spot = 12;

    List[12].name = "Сапегин Глеб";
    List[12].spot = 13;

    List[13].name = "Семенищева Кристина";
    List[13].spot = 14;

    List[14].name = "Ставров Павел";
    List[14].spot = 15;


    List[15].name = "Ткачук Екатерина";
    List[15].spot = 16;

    List[16].name = "Шкуратов Евгений";
    List[16].spot = 17;


    New_el.name = "****ТЕСТ*****";
    New_el.spot = 111;

    Add_to_beginning(New_el);
    Add_to_end(New_el, 16);
    Insert(New_el, 5);
    Deletion_from_beginning();
    Delete(5);

    HANDLE consoleOutput;
    consoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(consoleOutput, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);


    //вывод на дисплей
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << List[i].spot << ':' << ' ' << List[i].name << endl;
    };

    cout << ' ' << endl;
}
```

Comment: Что это вы такое странное написали? `include <windows.h> 
#using namespace std;`?

Comment: опечатался, исправил)

Comment: `int i = 20;
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        List[i + 1] = List[i];` - Итак, вы обращаетесь с самого начала к `List[21]` и `List[20]`, хотя последний элемент списка - `List[19]`. UB - дальше даже не смотрел...